# wxPython TaskBarIcon fails on elementaryOS

Tags: release-loki, development

In eOS 0.4 (Loki) the wxPython (3.0.2 gtk2 classic) wx.TaskBarIcon.IsAvailable() method returns False and of course ignoring this just results in no icon being shown. Is there a workaround for this or a plan to enable support?

I have seen applications which have problems, such as Dropbox and Skype, but have been able to work around those issues.